# Trying do to a Virtual WAN hub connection automatically based on a tag value on the Vnet. Parameter not found

Tags: azure, deployment, parameters, azure-rm-template, azure-policy

First some background information.

I'm trying to create an Azure Policy which searches for all vnets in all subscription with a specific tag and value. If it matches it should do a DeployIfNotExist deployment with an azure template, where the deployment will run in a different subscription than where the vnet exists. I am trying to solve this with a nested template, but am struggling with getting the vnet name from the policy and inserting it as a parameter inside the nested template.

The error i get when trying to create the definition in Azure is: The template parameter vnetname is not found.

If i replace parameters('vnetname') with the actual vnet name, this policy and deployment works, and i can create a remediation task that creates the vnet connection from the hub to the vnet in the other subscription.

I'm hoping someone either has a tip on how to solve this differently or that someone spots what's wrong wit my code. Here's a selection of the code from the deployment. Let me know if you need more of the code:

```
                                                                   "deployment":  {
                                                                            "properties":  {
                                                                                "mode": "Incremental",
                                                                                "parameters": {
                                                                                              },
                                                                                "template":  {
                                                                                      "$schema":  "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                                                                                      "contentVersion":  "1.0.0.0",
                                                                                      "parameters":  {
                                                                                                     },
                                                                                      "variables":  {
                                                                                                    },
                                                                                      "resources":  [
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
                                                                                                    "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
                                                                                                    "name": "nestedTemplate",
                                                                                                    "resourceGroup": "itp-net-pwe-rg",
                                                                                                    "subscriptionId": "c8fa0a01-84d0-4999-aec3-713e02ed248c",
                                                                                                    "properties": {
                                                                                                        "mode": "Incremental",
                                                                                                        "parameters":{
                                                                                                            "vnetname": {
                                                                                                                            "value": "[[field('name')]"
                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                        },
                                                                                                        "template":  {
                                                                                                            "$schema":  "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                                                                                                            "contentVersion":  "1.0.0.0",
                                                                                                            "parameters":  {
                                                                                                                "vnetname": {
                                                                                                                    "type": "string"
                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                           },
                                                                                                            "variables":  {
                                                                                                                          },
                                                                                                            "resources": [
                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                    "type":  "Microsoft.Network/virtualHubs/hubVirtualNetworkConnections",
                                                                                                                    "apiVersion":  "2020-06-01",
                                                                                                                    "name":  "itp-net-pwe-vwan-hub/source-to-hub-westeurope",
                                                                                                                    "location": "westeurope",
                                                                                                                    "dependsOn":  [
                                                                                                                                  ],
                                                                                                                    "properties":  {
                                                                                                                                        "remoteVirtualNetwork": {
                                                                                                                                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetname'))]" },
                                                                                                                                        "allowHubToRemoteVnetTransit": true,
                                                                                                                                        "allowRemoteVnetToUseHubVnetGateways": true,
                                                                                                                                        "enableInternetSecurity": false 
                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                        ]
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                     }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my own issue by putting the parameters at the correct level. The policy now works as expected.